# Projective and injective objects

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, projective-module, functors, injective-module

I'm trying to prove the following:

If $\mathcal{A}$ is an Abelian Category, then every object in $\mathcal{A}$ is projective if and only if every object is injective.

My attempt:
Since every object in $\mathcal{A}$ is projective, we can find an epic morphism from any object to the others. Consequently, every object is isomorphic to 0 and so every object is injective.
The converse is similar.

However, I don't think that my proof is true. Can anyone help?

Comment: The category of vector spaces is an explicit example where every object is projective and injective; run your proof on this example and see where it fails.

Comment: Right. I can't say that every morphism is epic. Do you have any idea about how to sketch the proof?

Comment: Both conditions are equivalent to every short exact sequence splitting.